# Can I define an object to a model with Play framework?

Tags: orm, playframework, ebean

`UserRole` is an abstract class, it has three concrete classes with three different roles. However, each time I crate a new User with a new Role, the Role remains `null`!

Here is the code of the User:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
  @Id
  public Long id;

  @Constraints.Required
  @Formats.NonEmpty
  @Column(unique = true)
  public String email;

  @Constraints.Required
  @Formats.NonEmpty
  @Column(unique = true)
  public String fullname;

  public String confirmationToken;

  @Constraints.Required
  @Formats.NonEmpty
  public String passwordHash;

  @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  public Date dateCreation;

  @Formats.NonEmpty
  public Boolean validated = false;

**public UserRole role;**
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the UserRole-class needs to be an entitiy as well, and I'm not sure whether this works with abstract classes.
Are you using ebeans or another ORM?